# Make pandas read hive's collect_list as a python list

Tags: python, sql, pandas, hive

When grouping and collecting elements in Hive using COLLECT_LIST, it's posible to put data in "array" form. It seems that pandas `.read_sql_query` can't recognize this hive output as a list and simply parse every row as a string. For example, after grouping and collecting in hive, rows look like this (here category_id is an int column on the table from where data is retrieved):

```
SELECT
user_id,
COLLECT_LIST(category_id) as session
FROM tracks_table
GROUP BY user_id

user_id    session
---------------------------------------------------------
42         [164792,164792,4862,4862,4862,164792,164792]
117        [2378,4598,69033,993332,1189345]
```

But when establishing the connection and executing the query with `pd.read_sql_query` pandas reads it like (string):

```
'[164792,164792,4862,4862,4862,164792,164792]'
'[2378,4598,69033,993332,1189345]' (as stings)
```

which is not memory efficient and implies me to write a custom (although simple) parsing function. The amount of data I'm dealing with is massive, so memory is a serious problem.

Is there an option to either change pandas parsing method or the query in order to read that as a list directly?

I'm aware that from pandas >= 1.3 there is a parameter `dtype` but it's unable to recognize `list` or `np.array` types. Thank you beforehand!

Comment: [please post a full example including code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). otherwise, not sure how to help. thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I put a minimal example of the query. Hope the question is clearer now.

Comment: it looks like there is a variable number of entries in each list. what are you hoping to get as a result?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I want to get the category navigation history of a user as a python list.

Comment: sorry - I mean what is the data structure that you're trying to achieve? pandas DataFrames are not designed to hold lists in each cell - this will not be more memory efficient than a list of lists.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Yes, I want to get an DataFrame. The problem is that there are other features involved rather than just the cats navigation, so I use pandas for posterior data preprocessing.

Comment: pandas is not designed to hold lists. so no, there's no way to do this other than to parse the strings. good luck!